# callback to notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, listview, dialog, fragment

I implemented a listview inside DialogFragment. Each item has a textview with a selector to simulate a radio group with option to select only one item at a time.
The problem is when the user clicks on an item I am updating the data on the adapter then calling to `notifyDataSetChanged()` and calling `dialog.dismiss()`.
The user don`t see the selection of item before the dialog is dismissed.
I fixed this by adding postdelay to dismiss functionality, Maybe there is a better solution for this problem?

This is my code:

```
public class SettingsPopupAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private List<SettingsItem>  _data;
    private Context             _con;
    public SettingsPopupAdapter(Context con, List<SettingsItem> data)
    {
        _con = con;
        _data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return _data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public SettingsItem getItem(int position)
    {
        return _data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(_con).inflate(R.layout.settings_popup_checkbox_row_item, parent, false);
            holder._text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.option_text);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        SettingsItem item = getItem(position);
        holder._text.setText(item.getItemLabel());
        holder._text.setSelected(item.isSelected());


        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView     _text;
    }

    public String getSelectedItem()
    {
        String selectedItem = null;
        for (SettingsItem item : _data)
        {
            if (item.isSelected())
            {
                selectedItem = item.getItemLabel();
                break;
            }
        }
        return selectedItem;
    }

    public List<String> getSelectedItems()
    {
        List<String> selectedOptions = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (SettingsItem item : _data)
        {
            if (item.isSelected())
            {
                selectedOptions.add(item.getItemLabel());
            }
        }

        return selectedOptions;
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<SettingsItem> items)
    {
        _data = items;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

This code is in the fragment from where I am opening the dialog :

```
private SettingsPopupAdapte _modAdapter;
private ArrayList<SettingsItem> _items;
_modAdapter = new SettingsPopupAdapter(getActivity(),_items);
_modificationListView.setAdapter(_modAdapter);

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{   
    String selectedItem =  _items.get(position).getItemLabel();
    selectExclusiveList(selectedItem);

    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt(Consts.MODIFICATION_TYPE_KEY, _type);
    b.putString(Consts.RESPONSE_DATA_KEY,selectedItem);
    _listener.onRetrieveData(b);

    //show the change before the dialog dismissed 
    getView().postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            dismiss();
        }
    },200);
}

private void selectExclusiveList(String selectedItem)
{
    for (SettingsItem item : _items)
    {
        item.setSelected(false);
        if (item.getItemLabel().equals(selectedItem))
        {
            item.setSelected(true);
        }
    }
    _modAdapter.setData(_items);
}
```